# ¿Como crear una carpeta con el nombre del usuario al subir un archivo (IMAGEN)? PHP

Tags: php, html, archivo

Buenas en esta ocasión quiero hacer que el usuario de mi sitio web inicie sesión tenga la opción de crear un álbum de fotos, ya yo puedo lograr que se muestre la foto que sube el usuario mediante el formulario con estos codigos:

CODIGO HTML:

```html
  <form action="album.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    
      <input type="file" name="image">
    
      <input type="submit" value="Subír" name="upload">
    
     </form>
```

CODIGO PHP :

```
    <?php 

    session_start();

    $usuario = $_SESSION['user'];

    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

        $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','image');
        if (!$conexion) {
            die("Error al conectarse a la base de datos.!". mysql_error());
        }
        else{

            $directorio="tmpAlbums/$usuario"; 
            $archivo=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $nombrearchivo=$_FILES['image']['name']; 

            move_uploaded_file($archivo, $directorio."/".$nombrearchivo); 

            $directorio=$directorio."/".$nombrearchivo; 
            mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO imagenes(imagen) 
            VALUES ('{$directorio}')"); 
        }


    }
?>
```

En la variable directorio "$directorio", si se fija luego de la carpeta tmpAlbums inserto la variable del usuario , es decír, como si fuese una carpeta con el nombre de ese usuario, pero es obvio que no me funcionó.

Pues en cuestión es eso, quiero que me ayuden a que cuando el usuario clickee para subir la foto esa foto se pueda mover a la carpeta de destino principal mas la carpeta del usuario que es la que quiero crear para que allí se almacenen todas sus fotos.

Nosé si me entienden de todas maneras por si las dudas estaré pendiente haganme saber si hay duda de mi propósito y de antemano gracias.!

Comment: Hola Abdiel, una duda la carpeta ya existe? Si no es asi tenes que crearla. $carpeta = '/ruta/a/mi/carpeta';
if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
    mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
}  y despues moves los archivos a esa carpeta

Comment: Hola juan.! , la unica carpeta que existe es tmpAlbums pero la del usuario no y eso es lo que quiero, que se cree una carpeta dentro de la carpeta tmpAlbums con el nombre del usuario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a tu codigo vos creas un directorio que seria adentro de que carpeta se tiene que crear la carpeta del usuario:

```
$directorio="tmpAlbums/$usuario";
```

Con este codigo verificas si existe el directorio y si no lo crea:

```
if (!file_exists($directorio)) {
    mkdir($directorio, 0777, true);
}
```

y despues moves las images a ese directorio:

```
move_uploaded_file($archivo, $directorio."/".$nombrearchivo);
```

Un ejemplo rapido de la creacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues que puedo decír , Juan me has ayudado, ya solucioné.! Muchas gracias,  ahora yo probaré lo demás. Mucha gracias.